# What kind of design shall i use in this scenario?

Tags: java, design-patterns, software-design

I am new to designing softwares, and I am trying to build a Tree like struct.
I have an empty interface like this:

```java
interface Node{
}
```

Two classes `NodeA` and `NodeB` implement this interface, and both have some specific attributes. Except that these are Nodes, they dont have anything common in them.

```java
class A implements Node {
    public String a;
    public A(String a){
       this.a = a;
    }
}

class B implements Node {
    public int a = 5;
    public String z = "xyz";

    public B(int a,String z){
         this.a = a;
         this.z = z;
    }
}
```

I have a a `class Parse` that creates instances of the above classes , depending on certain conditions.

```java
class Parse {
    List<Boolean> l;
    private static int i=0;
    Parse(List<Boolean> l){
        this.l = l;
    }

    private Node parseA() {
        return new A(/* param */); // Assume some parameters here
    }

    private Node parseB() {
        return new B(/* param */); // Assume some parameters here
    }

    private boolean getNextState(){
        return l.get(i++);
    }

    public Node parse(){
        boolean x = getNextState();
        if(x){
            return parseA();
        }
        else{
            return parseB();
        }
    }
}
```

Driver class:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Boolean> l = Arrays.asList(true,false); // so on...
        Parse p = new Parse(l);
        Node b = p.parse();  // not sure if its NodeA or NodeB
    }
}
```

After building the tree, i am planning to use visitor pattern to retrieve some attributes and do some operations.

> So at last, when i get a `Node b`, i want to access its attributes (of
>   `NodeA` or `NodeB`), which i know cant be done as Polymorphism doesnt
>   work that way.

I think that using `instanceof` ladder and type-casting arent proper solutions to it.
Sorry for this silly problem, but being new to designing, i aint getting what to do next. 
How shall one solve this design problem? can anyone share a small design structure for this, assuming that this structure will grow bigger and have ample of different nodes. [may be `Java Generics` help here]

 
Note: chaning above design is fine,but if possible, a small sample code is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this one for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned Visitor pattern can be used here.

```
interface Node {
    <T> T accept(NodeVisitor<T> visitor);
}

class A implements Node {
    public String a;
    public A(String a){
       this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T accept(NodeVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class B implements Node {
   public int a = 5;
   public String z = "xyz";

   public B(int a,String z){
        this.a = a;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T accept(NodeVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface NodeVisitor<T> {
    T visit(A node);
    T visit(B node);
}
```

Then define particular operation by implementing corresponsing visitor:

```
    NodeVisitor<Integer> visitor = new NodeVisitor<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer visit(A node) {
            // TODO do something with A node
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer visit(B node) {
            // TODO do something with B node
            return null;
        }
    };
```

and just call accept:

```
Node node = ...;
Integer result = node.accept(visitor);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends heavily on what you do in this section:

> So at last, when i get a Node b, i want to access its attributes (of
>   NodeA or NodeB), which i know cant be done as Polymorphism doesnt work
>   that way.

Personally, I would suggest you use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). The aim of this would be to have a common method, say, `visit` (which could reside within your `Node` interface, or maybe even create an `IVisitable` interface (or something along those lines). The aim of this method would be to handle the *visit* aspect of your algorithm.

So in essence, you would *delegate* what happens when you visit the node. If you need to do something specific, it might make sense to have this method take in the `visitor` as a method parameter so that your visitor can operate on the content of the node itself.